# Batch with IF ELSE and GOTO

Tags: batch-file, scripting

So, I am a beginner in batch scripting :)

Here is my code  :

```
@echo.
@echo off

Set USER_ADM=LocAdmin
Set pwd=%cd%
Set choix=%1

@echo.

:ch
cls
@echo.
@echo Choisis ce que tu veux ouvrir
@echo.
@echo 1. CMD
@echo 2. Regedit
@echo 3. MMC
@echo.
Set /P choix=Choix du programme a demarrer en %USER_ADM% (1-3) :
@echo off

if '%choix%' =='1' goto :cmd
if '%choix%'=='2' goto :regedit
if '%choix%'=='3' goto :mmc

REM :error
REM @echo %choix% N'est pas un chiffre entre 1 et 3 !
REM goto ch

:cmd
runas /user:%USER_ADM% C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe
goto ch

:regedit
runas /user:%USER_ADM% C:\Windows\regedit.exe
goto ch

:mmc
runas /user:%USER_ADM% "mmc %pwd%\MMC\Mymmc.msc"
goto ch

@pause > nul
```

I would like to have a message if I enter anything other than 1, 2 or 3.
I tried several things with "else" and goto error but nothing worked ...

Somebody can help ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: just insert code after `if '%choix%'=='3' goto :mmc`, like `echo wrong input` and `goto :ch`

Comment: Note: your `'` syntax works with `if`, but you should better use `"` to prevent various syntax errors. Also you might be interested in the [choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) command (which does it's own errorhandling, allowing only defined keys)

Comment: You have inserted `rem` statements in front of the three lines that deal with the "something else" situation, **BUT** since you have a `goto ch`, the next command is `cls` which will delete the message. Insert a `PAUSE` statement before the `goto ch`.

Comment: Read up on the `choice` command `choice /?` and you won't have that problem.

Comment: I will look at this `choice`.
And change my `'` for `"`

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

You already *have* code for dealing with this:

```
:ch
cls
@echo.
@echo Choisis ce que tu veux ouvrir
@echo Autres trucs francais je ne pouvais pas etre derange tapant (a)

:

if '%choix%' =='1' goto :cmd
if '%choix%'=='2' goto :regedit
if '%choix%'=='3' goto :mmc

REM :error
REM @echo %choix% N'est pas un chiffre entre 1 et 3 !
REM goto ch

:cmd
```

But there are two problems.

1. The code is commented out, meaning that a value other than `1..3` is just going to drop through to the code that does option one.
2. Even if you uncomment that code, it will print the error message and immediately return up to the `:ch` label, clearing the screen.

The fix for the first one is easy, simply remove the `rem` keywords from those three lines.

For the second problem, you could go one of two ways (at least).

First option is to insert a `pause` command immediately before `goto :ch`. This will leave the error message on the screen until you enter something.

Second option is to *not* clear the screen but instead just reprint the menu. This can be done by moving the `cls` to *before* the `:ch` label.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Apologies for my atrocious French, specifically (but not necessarily limited to) lack of accents :-)